# User Claims always empty when calling API from server-side Blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have a .NET Core Project that hosts a WebAPI and a Server-Side Blazor Application. The application uses the default authentication and authorization via an `IdentityDbContext` and uses the default `AuthenticationStateProvider` for Blazor. As I want this app to potentially move to Client-Side Blazor at some point in the future, I have been keeping the Server-Side logic in the API and calling it through `HttpClient` which I have manually injected in Startup using `services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();`

The issue I am having is that the User Claims (i.e. `HttpContext.User`) are empty in the API Controllers when making calls to the API. When I say empty, the `HttpContext.User` object is not null, but all the values are at their defaults. The expected behaviour is that the Claims would be populated with the Identity information for the logged-in user.

Strangely, the identity cookie `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` is present in the browser, and the values in the `AuthenticationStateProvider` service are all as expected for the logged-in user. To me, this indicates that everything is configured correctly in terms of Authentication and Identity and that the issue is somehow related to `HttpClient` or the Api Controllers.

I have tried:

- Setting `HttpOnly` to false on the cookie configuration and retrieving the cookie manually via JSInterop to attach the `HttpClient` headers. This failed due to API calls beginning before JSInterop had finished grabbing the cookies.
- Manually injecting `HttpClient` into my `ApiService` via `services.AddHttpClient<IApiService, ApiService>();`
- Copying the Startup configuration from a working project and overwriting my one
- Changing the order of the configured services in various different ways
- Several different cookie configurations
- Creating and using a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider`
- Following several different guides from the official Microsoft Documentation
- Reviewing countless articles and Stackoverflow questions on similar issues and trying out their suggestions

I also tried manually adding the authentication cookie to the `HttpClient` via the following:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
{
    var httpContextAccessor = s.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    string authToken = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Identity.Application"];

    var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseCookies = false
    });

    if (authToken != null)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", $".AspNetCore.Identity.Application={authToken}");
    }

    var request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}/");
    return client;
});
```

This solution failed as `httpContextAccessor` returned null when the delegate was invoked. I understand that there is no HttpContext with a SignalR connection, however, I would still expect an HttpContext when either the app is first loaded, the page is refreshed, or an API call is made. I also tried a null check version of this where it would only proceed if `HttpContext` was non-null, but that also failed as `HttpContext` was never non-null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by passing the authentication token directly to the Blazor app and then adding it to `HttpClient` that way.

While my app is hosted in an MVC view, I understand that the most common way to host a Blazor app is through a Razor Page. For anyone else experiencing this issue, the Razor Page modification would be as follows.

**_Host.cshtml**

```
@{
    var token = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Identity.Application"];
}

<app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" param-Token="token" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</app>
```

The MVC solution involves getting the token at the controller level and passing it down. The code for that is as follows.

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var token = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Identity.Application"];
    return View(token);
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model string

...

<app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" param-Token="@Model" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</app>
```

And finally, regardless of which method was used above, the Blazor app would be modified to add the token to the `HttpClient` as follows.

**App.razor**

```
@inject HttpClient HttpClient

...

@code
{
    [Parameter] public string Token { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", $".AspNetCore.Identity.Application={Token}");
    }
}
```